# Is it possible to drill through a peltier?

Tags: peltier, cooling

I want something like this:

[image]
[image]

But I don't want to pay 30 bucks (USD) for a single peltier. Can I just drill a normal one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps (drilling ceramic is not trivial), but it won't work anymore.

The junctions are spread out over the surface and they are in series so damaging one connection breaks the string. It might be possible to jumper over the damaged sections, but I doubt it would be effective.

You can see the little blocks in the edge view of your 2nd photo.